# Archimedean spiral - rotation of polar axis

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

One of the examples of curves in polar coordinates in my book is an Archimedean spiral 
$$
r=a\theta
$$
and the book says that the equation
$$
r=a\theta + b
$$
also represents and Archimedean spiral because if we would rotate the polar axis through an angle $\alpha = -\frac{b}{a}$ it would change to the previous one $r=a\theta$. Can anyone explain to me how is the rotation made? I don't think that I get it quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spiral $ r=a\theta$  goes through origin. Rotate the full spiral as a rigid  spiral  by an angle $\beta. $

$ r= a(\theta + \beta) =    a\theta + a \beta = a\theta + b$. The spiral has nonzero value where it cuts x-axis. Only after looking at $\beta$ in the opposite direction does the spiral goes through x-axis.

Comment: Right, so rotating the polar axis by an angle $\alpha$ is just adding $\alpha$ to each angle $\theta$ (in the formula $r=f(\theta)$ if we are talking about a specific curve), that is clear for me now, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome.